# On a theorem of Eisenbud and Koh

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

There is Theorem by Eisenbud and Koh which can be stated as follows:

**Theorem.**  Let $P$ be a set of points in $\mathbb{P}^r$, and let $d \ge 2$ be an integer. If, for all $k \ge 1$, no $dk + 2$ points of $P$ lie in a projective $k-$plane,
then $P$ impose independent conditions on forms of degree $d$; in fact, there is a multilinear form of degree $d$ containing any subset consisting of all but one of the
points, but missing the last.

> **Question.** Do we need to consider $P$ to be a set of distinct points, or a locally complete intersection zero-dimensional subscheme
> will work, where the numbers in the theorem will be replaced by
> length?

Comment: The result is in: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1015517

Comment: I know about the result. But they consider a set of points. Can we replace the set of points in the theorem  by lci zero dimensional subschemes ?

Comment: My comment was meant to help people (like me) who needed information about the theorem. Unfortunately I don’t have access to the article but possibly others might. Sorry for being unclear. I meant, the Eisenbud-Koh result you’re asking about is there.